# PHP curl_init() produces error 500 with IPv6

Tags: php, curl, php-7, ipv6, php-curl

As title says - PHP curl_init() produces error 500 with IPv6 but works fine on IPv4

Temporary workaround

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

Any ideas how to solve this??

Comment: How could curl_setopt help, if the curl_init already produced a HTTP 500?

Comment: What server is returning 500 status code? Yours or the remote machine?

Comment: It works when CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE is set to CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4. with CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6 - it does not work. Strange, eh?

Comment: So how to set up php-curl to IPV6 - no. Says yes in php info. Can't find anything on the subject. Apparently curl is smart for IPv6, but I can't find out why it produces an error on IPv6 and on IPv4 - scripts called with curl work. If it was not strange, most probably I would not ask. He-he!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, it is the same machine - scripts communicating to each other.

Comment: HTTP status code aren't machine-wide, they happen at response level.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, how does this help in this case?

Comment: Because when something doesn't work you gather diagnostic information. You're currently getting an error that means "please check the log files to see what the error is" and we don't even know what script is triggering it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, no errors in the log related to the script. I personally do not have IPv6 but servers do. Can't test and run from IPV6 network to see why it is returning 500. Funny situation. What I did was curl_init() in php from a script on the machine to call another script on the same machine. IPV6 fails but if set to v4 - runs. Out of weekend ideas for now.